# Getting web search results using Google Custom Search and Google .Net Client Liberary ERROR 400

Tags: c#, google-custom-search

I'm trying to use Google custom search to retrieve google web search's URLs.
this is my code:

```
String query = "***";
        string apiKey = "********";
        string cx = "****";


       var svc = new Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CustomsearchService
       (new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            ApiKey = apiKey
        });
        var listRequest = svc.Cse.List(query);

        listRequest.Cx = cx;
        listRequest.Start = 1;
        var search = listRequest.Execute();
        foreach (var result in search.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", result.Title);
            Console.WriteLine("Link: {0}", result.Link);

        }
```

> The service customsearch has thrown an exception:
>   Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Invalid
>   Value [400] Errors [  Message[Invalid Value] Location[ - ]
>   Reason[invalid] Domain[global] ]

I apreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: thank you for your response

acoording to

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors

code 400 Indicates that a request parameter has an invalid value. The locationType and location fields in the error response provide information as to which value was invalid.

that's all I got from goole plus my question here :)

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out,the problem was in the request, int cx parameter
I'will include the new code after I finish my project
thank you

Comment: Would you please provide the complete and correct code, so that we others may benefit.